# Trying to use FileReader with typescript and react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filereader

```
import { useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';
```

import { EventHandler, ReactEventHandler, useState } from 'react';
import { taxonomySelectorName } from '../../../../../state/header.state';
import { TAXONOMY_SELECTOR, HEADER_TESTS } from '../../../../../constants/header.constants';
import useMandatoryOptionsServices from '../../../../../services/mandatoryOptions.services';
import { options } from '../../../../../constants/mandatoryOptions.constants';
import { IOption } from '../../../../../types/mandatoryOptions/mandatoryOptions.types';
import * as Style from './mandatoryOption.styles';

const MandatoryOptions = () => {
const isTaxonomyDefaultName = useRecoilValue(taxonomySelectorName) === TAXONOMY_SELECTOR.PLEASE_SELECT_TAXONOMY;
const { setModalAction, handelMandatoryOptionActions } = useMandatoryOptionsServices();
const [nameAndContent, setNameAndContent] = useState({ name: '', content: '' });

```
const handleClick = (type: string) => {
    handelMandatoryOptionActions();
    setModalAction(type);
};

const importFile = () => {
    document.getElementById('1')?.click();
};

const handleChangeFile = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e);
    const files = e.target.files;
    console.log(files);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (r) => {
        console.log(r);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
};

return (
    <>
        <Style.Hr />
        <Style.MandatoryOptionsContainer data-testid={HEADER_TESTS.MANDATORY_OPTIONS}>
            {options.map((option: IOption, index) => (
                <Style.MandatoryOption
                    onClick={isTaxonomyDefaultName ? undefined : () => handleClick(option.functionType)}
                    key={index}
                    isTaxonomyDefaultName={isTaxonomyDefaultName}
                    data-testid={option.dataTestId}
                >
                    {option.content}
                </Style.MandatoryOption>
            ))}
            <Style.MandatoryOption
                onClick={isTaxonomyDefaultName ? undefined : () => importFile()}
                key={'import csv'}
                isTaxonomyDefaultName={isTaxonomyDefaultName}
                data-testid={'import csv'}
            >
                import csv
            </Style.MandatoryOption>
            <input type="file" id="1" onChange={(e) => handleChangeFile(e)} />
        </Style.MandatoryOptionsContainer>
    </>
);
```

};

export default MandatoryOptions;

Hi I am trying to get my file content and my code doesn't work...
The console.log's do not appear in the console at all.

Can someone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it should work, I need more details.

Comment: @fixiabis Can u please tell me which details u need?

Comment: The code of the component.

Comment: @fixiabis 
I am adding code to the question

Comment: The key point is here, right? https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-wildflower-w8mo4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What is mean key point?
In your sandbox code I can see the logs in console : )
Why can I see them in my code?